# @Column and @Table in java class is asking to configure buildpath in eclipse?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I am New to Hibernate ..when i wrote below code

```
package com.slokam.hib3;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name="A_TPH")
public class A {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String name;

public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

}
```

Here At the first line (com.slokam.hib3) hibernate is showing error that configure build path if i add @Table  or @Column entity.. I added all the jars of hibernate..Solution plz..

Comment: `hibernate is showing error`? Are you using any IDE, like Eclipse?

Comment: I am using eclipse ide

Comment: You added the jars to your lib folder, or you configured project's build path? If you right-click the jars (`hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar` or similar) in project structure, under `Build Path` menu, do you have `Add to Build Path` or `Configure Build Path`?